# VLookup throwing an error

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I have a sheet similar to this:

```
   A         B        C        D        E        F
1  Name      Age      Number   Gender   Player   player No.
2  Droid12   11                M        Droid12  F3
3  R2D2      13                M        C3P0     F12
4  C3P0      12                F        Bot13    Y7
5  YVH7707   11                F        J34      Z2
6  Bot13     15                M
7  Slim33    13                F
8  ABot43    14                F
9  DBo11     11                M
10 J34       12                M
```

I am trying to fill in Column C with the player number, if the person in question has one (Imagine that the sheet is thousands of time this large).

I have the following VLookup function in each cell in C (copied down from C1, of course):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, $E$2:$F$5, 2,FALSE)
```

And am getting the result:

```
#N/A
```

When I try to step through, I get the error

> Sheet1!$A$2 = Droid12: The cell currently being evaluated contains a
>   constant

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT

I've tried some of these fixes, with no positive results. I tried this in C1-C3:

C2 contains:

```
=IF(A2=E2, F2, FALSE)
```

With the result that cell C2 contains the value Droid12

C3 contains:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, $E$2:$F$3, 2, FALSE)
```

and is getting a #N/A error (with the same error:

> Sheet1!$A$2 = Droid12: The cell currently being evaluated contains a
>   constant

The values are all standardized (Trimmed,etc...), and there is definitely a match in the range I'm comparing to, so I really can't see what I'm doing wrong. Anyone ever experience this before?

**edit 2**

I fixed it, turns out I had Player No. In column E and Player in Column F, so the comparison for some reason was not running correctly. I switched those two entities around, and the VLOOKUP worked fine. Weird, but I'm not complaining. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it happens if there is no exact match. Try to use trim and wildcard chars to allow matching to skip spaces. For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*",TRIM(A2),"*"), $E$2:$F$5, 2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:-

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE)), "",VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE))
```

In Simple, formula is

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE)
```

Issue is caused due to the Range, which is mentioned as `$E$2:$F$5`.

When you are trying to drag the formula for the rest of cells, Range is getting updated wrongly. This is causing issue.

The Cell which doesn't match the actual value then `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A`. To overcome this, I have placed a `IF` condition to check any error and display empty if fails otherwise the value.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the constant error can be avoided if you have the reference data on the furtherest left-hand column on all sheets.

i.e.
Column A1 = Description plus info A2:etc (Sheet 1 and Sheet 2)

Answer (score 1):

The N/A is the result of the name you are looking up not being in the list.  This is normal behavior for the VLOOKUP function.

To eliminate the NA being displayed try this formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$5, 2, FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$5, 2, FALSE))
```

This checks to see if the result of the lookup is N/A.  If it is, then display blank ("").  If the result is not NA then display the lookup value.

One issue with this solution is the lookup will be performed twice on each record that is found (once to check if it is N/A and once again to display the value (although Excel may be optimizing for this situation).